# preprocessor/ macro expansion with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, preprocessor

From time to time, I use `write-host` in my scripts to do poor-man debugging/ logging, but having all of them fire on each run clutters my screen with tons of unneeded info.
Of course, I can comment/ uncomment the ones I need for the current run but this is a lot of editing and very error-prone.

here is what I finally came to:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [parameter()]
    [string[]]$dbg_points=@('*')
)

$debug   = ($PSCmdlet.myInvocation.BoundParameters['Debug'].isPresent -eq $true)
$dbg_all = $dbg_points -contains '*'

if(($debug) -and ($dbg_all -or ($dbg_points -contains 'foo'))) { Write-host '@foo debug point' }
if(($debug) -and ($dbg_all -or ($dbg_points -contains 'bar'))) { Write-host '@bar debug point' }

if(($debug) -and ($dbg_all -or ($dbg_points -contains 'foo') -or ($dbg_points -contains 'bar'))) { Write-host 'common debug point' }
```

this does the job but is a lot of typing on each place where I want to have some debugging/ logging info, especially for the common points.

with some other language I would have defined some kind of macro/ preprocessor directive, say `DBG(foo) {...}` or `DBG(foo,bar) {...}` which would have expanded  respectivly to to

```
if(($debug) -and ($dbg_all -or ($dbg_points -contains 'foo'))) {...}
```

and

```
if(($debug) -and ($dbg_all -or ($dbg_points -contains 'foo') -or ($dbg_points -contains 'bar'))) {...}
```

but I dont think this is possible in powershell.

do you know a better, more *powershell-ish* way of doing it?

oh, I forgot to tell you... I'm stuck with v2 on that computer and ca not install a newer version

Comment: Seems that this is the sort of thing that `Write-Debug` was designed for...

Comment: Use a function (or logging/etc. framework).

Comment: Bill_Stewart: `write-debug` is just a king of `write-host` witch fires only when -Debug is used on the command line but it also suspend execution and is in no way conditional.

Comment: You can also use `Write-Verbose` if you don't like `Write-Debug`...

Comment: Bill_Stewart: my question is not related to what comes between { and } but to what comes **before**. my question is how to prevent all this typing while keeping the conditional execution of the scriptblock.